# Error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load! + Error: Callback was already called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

When I start/restart my server, I sometimes get errors, yet my server eventually starts anyways after a few attempts to boot without editing any code. Why is this happening?

**Here's the full error message:**

```
node --debug-brk=11125 --nolazy app.js 
Debugger listening on [::]:11125
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
/home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^
Error: Callback was already called.
    at _toString (/home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:30:31)
    at /home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/loadHooks.js:106:18
    at taskCallback (/home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:468:21)
    at /home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/orm/build-orm.js:57:23
    at /home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline.js:213:22
    at _toString (/home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:49:16)
    at /home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:258:21
    at called (/home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:40:16)
    at /home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/index.js:69:22
    at wrapper (/home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3602:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/home/webdeveloper/Projects/XYZ/XYZ%20Server/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:331:16)
```

Please Help.

Comment: What ur version of waterline?